# Git: diff between refs and additionally using files pattern?

Tags: git, git-diff

When I run this command: `git diff --name-only 1.9.0..1.9.1`
I get:

```
RELEASE.rst
mail_activity_history/__manifest__.py
mail_activity_history/models/mail_activity.py
```

I want to limit paths to only those having `__manifest__.py` at the end.

If I try this: `git diff --name-only 1.9.0..1.9.1 -- */__manifest__.py`

It returns empty string, meaning nothing was found.

If I do not use `asterisk`, and specify path, like:

```
git diff --name-only 1.9.0..1.9.1 -- mail_activity_history/__manifest__.py
```

It outputs:

```
mail_activity_history/__manifest__.py
```

Why path with `asterisk` does not work when I want diff between refs?

P.S. I noticed that if I use for example `HEAD~10` instead of `ref1..ref2`, it does work with asterisk.
P.S.S `git version 2.7.4`

Comment: The `paths` arguments to `git diff` are not pathspecs so you cannot use `*` in them this way at all. The case that seemed to work is probably the result of having the *shell* expand the name. Note that the shell also expands the `*` in other cases; to prevent the shell from expanding `*/__manifest__.py`, you need to quote it. However, quoting it doesn't really help since these paths are not pathspecs and therefore don't allow globbing.

Comment: So what could be an alternative to get desired behavior?

Comment: Use `git diff --name-only` to generate a full diff, then filter the resulting names.

Comment: Well I thought it was possible to do it solely with git

Comment: It probably should be. If `git diff` took pathspecs instead of just paths, it would be.